# PHP / Json : create an array (to pars as Json) without quotes

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Using highcharts.js, I need to pass series data as numbers, without quotes.

My actual JSON is like this:

```
{"name":"SHOP NUM 2","data":"[22377.00,48922.00,24280.00]"}
```

But I need in this manner (without the quotes in data values):

```
{"name":"SHOP NUM 2","data":[22377.00,48922.00,24280.00]}
```

This is the PHP that create the final array:

```
    $data = array();
    $this->getSerie();

    $data[0]['serie'] = $this->serie;

    $this->getAccount();

    for ($i=1;$i<count($this->account);$i++) {

        $account = $this->account[$i];

        $value = $this->getData($account);

        $data['data'][$i-1]['name'] = $account;
        $data['data'][$i-1]['data'] = $value;
    }

    $this->result = $data;



function getData($id) {

$data = $this->data;

$total = '[';

foreach ($data as $datakey=>$datavalue) {

    if ($datavalue['id']===$id) {

        $subtotal = $data[$datakey]['total'];
        if ($subtotal===null) {
            $subtotal=0.00;
        }
        $total = $total.(float)$subtotal.',';

    }

}

$total = rtrim($total, ",");
$total = $total.']';

return $total;

}
```

And this code returns, for example var_dump($total)

```
string(31) "[10,20,30,50,0,0,0,0,40,0,0,25,0,0,0]"
```

Final Array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [serie] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-13
                    [1] => 2015-07-20
                    [2] => 2015-07-27
                    [3] => 2015-08-03
                    [4] => 2015-08-10
                    [5] => 2015-08-17
                    [6] => 2015-08-24
                    [7] => 2015-08-31
                    [8] => 2015-09-07
                    [9] => 2015-09-14
                    [10] => 2015-09-21
                    [11] => 2015-09-28
                    [12] => 2015-10-05
                    [13] => 2015-10-12
                    [14] => 2015-10-19
                )

        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => SHOP 1
                    [data] => [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => SHOP 2
                    [data] => [22377,48922,24280,23007,0,17585,20860,21495,17550,18320,18320,32970,40265,36220,0,41755,18180]
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => SHOP 3
                    [data] => [0,65,0,176,0,950,170,270,110,20,40,70,50,30,210]
                )



        )

)
```

Last, with a `echo json_encode($this->result,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`  I have the initial JSON, with quote around "data".

To complete, I'm using that data in a `for` cycle in javascript, like this:

```
for (i=0;i<data['data'].length;i++) {

                series.push(data['data'][i]);

            }
```

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Why downvote without an explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look further into using [php's `json_encode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

you can construct your entire reply as a php object, and use json_encode on it to get a proper json object.

```
$arrayvalue = array("values"  => array(1, 2, 3));
echo json_encode($arrayvalue);
```

this will output the following :

```
{"values" : [1,2,3]}
```

Or to put it simply ; do not try to contruct the array via string concatenation, but instead make a php array with the proper values and let json_encode sort out how to render it as json array.

Besides probably being easier, it's also cleaner and less confusing than building your own json reply using string concatenation.

Comment: This is the correct answer. But you're being way too easy on him -- it's not a case of "might want to..", or "try not to.."; more a case of it being crazy not to use `json_encode()`! He can basically replace almost all of his code with a single line.

Comment: I'll try asap, thank you for the moment. @Simba : I did not understand your comment, crazy, or not crazy. I'm here to learn more and more. How I could optimize my code with a single line? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @sineverba - the point is that the `json_encode()` function exists in PHP and is specifically designed to do the work of building the JSON string from an array or object structure. So assuming you start off with a PHP array in the format you want the JSON to end up, all the code where you're looping through the array and joining values and commas and `[]` characters can be replaced with a single `json_encode()` call. You should never need to construct a JSON string manually.